# LIBGDX Button to turn of Background music

Tags: android, libgdx

In the game that I am creating using LIBGDX, I have a .mp3 file streaming in the background. I want to create a button that when pressed by the user it will mute the background music and when pressed again it will play the music. Could anyone give me hints on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the documentation here](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Sound.html).

It has a play method to play the tune. Similarly it has pause/resume methods. I think this is what you are looking for.

**__UPDATE__**

mute/unmute and pause/resume are totally two different functionality. Here I will give an example for pause/resume.

```
...
//This is the tune that you play.
private Sound backgroundMusic;
private long backgroundMusicId;
...
ImageButton pauseButton = new ImageButton(
               GraphicsUtils.getSmoothDrawableFromFile("pauseUp.png"),
               GraphicsUtils.getSmoothDrawableFromFile("pauseDown.png"));
ImageButton playButton = new ImageButton(
                GraphicsUtils.getSmoothDrawableFromFile("playUp.png"),
                GraphicsUtils.getSmoothDrawableFromFile("playDown.png"));

pauseButton.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                Gdx.app.log("BlahScreen", "pauseButtonPressed");
                backgroundMusic.pause(backgroundMusicId);
            }
        });

playButton.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                Gdx.app.log("BlahScreen", "playButtonPressed");
                backgroundMusic.play(1.0f);
            }
        });
```

Comment: How do I set the button to pause/mute the music when clicked?

Comment: Sorry for my poor description and written question, I am new to game development.

When I say I have created a Button. It is a Texture in the form of a button. I want this button to mute the music which it is clicked and then for the music to 'unmute' when clicked again.

Comment: Consider using Scene2D for your UI (it's part of libGDX). It makes working with buttons and other screen elements a real breeze. You can add a button and register an event listener for it to start/stop your music.